# Calculate distance of a point to the nearest road out of selected roads

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, distance

I have a set of points that represent animal-vehicle collisions and a a layer of roads. 
I want to calculate the distance between each collision point and the nearest road, but need to exclude the road where the collision happened. I am aware that the `Near` tool can help me with this, but can't find a way to exclude the road where the collision took place.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You would need to define a business logic for specifying the road at which the collision occurred. Is it stored as a point attribute? If not, one could find the nearest road for every point and calculate the distance to the next nearest road, if this is what you want. You also have to think a bit on how do you want to measure the distance from the points to the roads - by using the line's midpoint, start/end, nearest vertex etc. Having a primitive picture with some drawings would definitely help.

Comment: workaround copy the entire dataset but exclude the nearest road... not very automated but will give you a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest workflow would be to use a select by location to select all the roads that do not intersect the points layer, then create a new layer from selected.  This will allow you to use the new layer as your dataset for the near tool.

The select would work by selecting all roads, then choosing "remove from current selection" as your selection method when doing the actual select by location.